# Is it possible to make a statement about ways I think MSE could improve?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

My apologies if this question doesn't fit here - I am not sure where this question would best be asked.

I have been feeling for some time that I would like to make a suggestion for how math stack exchange could improve, but I am not sure where would be most appropriate. Is this an suitable forum for such commentary? Is there somewhere else that I should go? Is my opinion not relevant because I am not a very significant user of MSE?

Comment: This is exactly the place for such commentary.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'not very significant user' but (guessing) I suppose if you feel you might be repeating suggestions already made by not having been on the sites for long then you should use the search functionality to see if your concerns have been addressed before and how they were answered then.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. I will make a post.

Comment: In general, it is best not to ask if it is okay to ask---asking to ask *is* off-topic.  The best way to determine if something is on-topic or not is to simply *ask*, and see how the community feels about it.

Comment: Note the tags "discussion" and "feature-request" on Meta Math.SE.  Presumably one or the other is suitable for a post suggesting improvements to policies or software.

Comment: "Is my opinion not relevant because I am not a very significant user of MSE?" That is not true, but please make sure to search meta and ensure that your suggestion is not already discussed. If it is, then your fresh attempt to discuss that may become a duplicate of that question. Spend a good 15 minutes at least searching, because a lot of stuff has already been debated upon here. Another point concerns what part of MSE you think could improve : the culture, the interface, the help page etc. because some of those improvements are not in the hands of users/mods here.